# Access to instance public properties from prototype function (IIFE)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a library that's composed of more parts to function properly.

```
var Brain = (function () {
    var publics = {
        studies: {
            "ManagedVehicles": "\\Brain\\Studies\\ManagedVehicles"
        }
    };

    publics.study = function (study) {
        if (! publics.studies.hasOwnProperty(study)) {
            throw new BrainInvalidStudy(study + " study does not exist.");
        }

        return new BrainStudy(study);
    }

    return publics;
}());

function BrainInvalidStudy(message) {
    this.message = message;
    // Use V8's native method if available, otherwise fallback
    if ("captureStackTrace" in Error)
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, BrainInvalidStudy);
    else
        this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}

var BrainStudy = (function () {

    function BrainStudy (study) {
        this.study = study;
    }

    BrainStudy.prototype = (function (userId) {
        var publics = {};
        var self    = this;

        console.log(this);

        function query (data) {
            return $.ajax('/api/brain/study', {
                data: data
            });
        }

        publics.of = function (userId) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                console.log(this); // window
                console.log(self); // window
                console.log(self.study); // undefined

                query({
                    what: self.study,
                    who:  userId
                }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    resolve(response);
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    reject();
                })
            });
        }

        return publics;
    }());

    return BrainStudy;
}());

BrainInvalidStudy.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
BrainInvalidStudy.prototype.name = "BrainInvalidStudy";
BrainInvalidStudy.prototype.constructor = BrainInvalidStudy;
```

The problem is that `console.log(self.study)` is always `undefined`, which prevents me to use the property defined in the constructor from the base Brain class.

I've read other questions that do a similar thing, but none of those use IIFEs like I do.

EDIT: Thank you all guys, I've used a combination of both your answers, here's the end result:

```
var BrainStudy = (function () {

    function BrainStudy (study) {
        this.study = study;
    }

    (function (prototype) {
        function query (data) {
            return $.ajax('/api/brain/study', {
                data: data
            });
        }

        prototype.of = function (userId) {
            var self = this;

            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                query({
                    what: self.study,
                    who:  userId
                }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    resolve(response);
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    reject();
                })
            });
        }
    }(BrainStudy.prototype));

    return BrainStudy;
}());
```

Comment: How do you create your `BrainStudy`. Do you use `new BrainStudy()` ? Seems the problem that you do not create this object using `new` operator

Comment: I am using it, look inside Brain module, the `study()` method.

Comment: Yes, but how do you call your `of` method? You `this` is this case should be pointer to your class instance, not to `window`. Share your code where you call `of` method

Comment: I am just testing it in the console. I'll share a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the `self` variable inside `public.of`:

```
publics.of = function (userId) {
    var self = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        query({
            what: self.study,
            who:  userId
        }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            resolve(response);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            reject();
        })
    });
}
```

Currently `self` is equal to `window` because it is initialized in an anonymous function and not in the context of any object.

Answer (score 1):

your context is not `BrainStudy`, try this

```
function BrainStudy (study) {
  this.study = study;
}

(function(proto) {
  function log(args) {
    console.log(args);
  }

  proto.of = function() {
    log(this.study);
  };

})(BrainStudy.prototype);

var b = new BrainStudy(12);
b.of();
```

or

```
function BrainStudy (study) {
  this.study = study;
}

BrainStudy.prototype = (function() {
  var proto = {};
  function log(args) {
    console.log(args);
  }

  proto.of = function() {
    var self = this;
    log(this.study);
    log(self.study);
  };
  return proto;
})();

var b = new BrainStudy(12);
b.of();
```